# Environment Variables on Heroku and Mailgun Problems with Phoenix Framework

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I was following [this](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku) guide on deploying to Heroku and [this](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/sending-email) one for sending email.

Everything works fine in development. My variables are set in Heroku:

```
heroku config
...
MAILGUN_DOMAIN:  https://api.mailgun.net/v3/xxxxxx.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_KEY:     key-3-xxxxxx
...
```

And loaded from the config files like so:

```
config :take_two, Mailer,
    domain: System.get_env("MAILGUN_DOMAIN"),
    key: System.get_env("MAILGUN_KEY")
```

However when I try to send email on Heroku when the Mailgun config is set from environment variables I get this error:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in IO.chardata_to_string/1
    (elixir) lib/io.ex:346: IO.chardata_to_string(nil)
    (elixir) lib/path.ex:467: Path.join/2
    (elixir) lib/path.ex:449: Path.join/1
             lib/client.ex:44: Mailgun.Client.send_without_attachments/2
```

This happens when the domain is not set for the Mailgun Client. But it is supposed to be set from the environment variable. I made a simple module to test:

```
defmodule TakeTwo.Mailer do
    require Logger

    use Mailgun.Client,
        Application.get_env(:take_two, Mailer) 

    def blank_shot do
        Logger.info Application.get_env(:take_two, Mailer)[:domain]
        Logger.info Application.get_env(:take_two, Mailer)[:key]
        send_email from: "steve@xxx.com", to: "speggy@xxx.com", subject: "Hello", text: "This is a blank shot"
    end
```

When I run `TakeTwo.Mailer.blank_shot` I see the correct domain/key variables logged followed by the error. I am not sure how to debug the Mailgun client remotely.

*Finally, if I recreate* the above module in the shell (after running `heroku run iex -S mix`) it works just fine!?

I feel like when the original module is being loaded perhaps the environment variables have yet to be loaded??

Comment: When I looked at Chris Mcoords mailgun client example, the one difference I noticed was that ```use``` gets passed the module, and then a key word list which include domain and key. Your example only passes it the module and the ```Application.get_env((:take_two, Mailer))``` which returns a tuple. https://github.com/chrismccord/mailgun

Comment: Thanks @TheBrofessor, I tried it both ways and it seemed to work locally. I'm pretty sure Application.get_env returned a keyword list. I am noticing that Chris's example is using a module attribute so I tried that with the same results. `TakeTwo.Mailer.conf` shows both values are `nil`. I found a related issue on that repo – I feel like the Heroku build pack is not loading the environment variables before compiling. So I guess that's the next piece to look at.

Comment: Ohhh snap. https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir#specifying-config-vars-to-export-at-compile-time has the answer. Turns out you need to explicitly define which Heroku config variables are to be exported at compile time. Silly me assumed they would all be exported automatically.

Comment: Nice find, I would have assumed the same ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was a little buried in a comment so I wanted to make it easier to find. As the other answer mentions, the environment variables aren't available, but the buildpack lets you configure them to be:

I created a `elixir_buildpack.config` file and added the following:

```
config_vars_to_export=(DATABASE_URL MAILGUN_DOMAIN MAILGUN_KEY SECRET_KEY_BASE)
```

Comment: Worth noting that this has been deprecated, and all config vars are now exported by default. https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir#migrating-from-previous-build-pack

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables aren't available at build time. I had the same issue and decided to get rid of the macro carrying the configuration. You can use [this patch](https://github.com/chrismccord/mailgun/pull/21) to move on.